# Spring Web Service, JMS, Long Running Job

Tags: java, spring, jms

I want to implement a `Spring` web service to handle a long running process. In requests to this service client specify the job parameters and I need to response back with a job id to track the status of the job.

Client will request again with the job id and service should respond with the status (pending, inprogress, completed) of the job.

According to the requirement given, I need to use a `JMS` queue to queue up jobs and once the job is completed a result object (Which has the job id) will be added to another queue. So client will be able to get the result by requesting with the job id.

Currently I am able to create Job objects from given parameters, added them to a queue using `JMS`, a consumer process the job and put the result object to a another queue. Also I tried to generate unique string id as the job id using `UUID`. But I'm not sure how to handle this status checking and taking result back from the result queue. Also i think if there is a way to generate an integer id it will be more elegant, Any ideas will be highly appreciated.

Comment: instead of using another queue to track status/completion it will be better to use database table

Comment: Is that mean I need to store job status with job id in a database table?

Comment: yup you can have a DB table to keep generated JOBID and its status